# Cannot start PostgreSQL database: Invalid primary and secondary checkpoints

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, postgresql-10

My specific problem is that we are unable to restart our postgreSQL database.

We have an ubuntu server (release 18.04) with PostgreSQL 10 installed. I commonly revise my IP address in the pg_hba.conf file to allow connections from pgAdmin on my home machine. When changes are made to the config file, this requires a restart of postgresql to take effect. I did a stop and start: `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop`, followed by `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start`

Unfortunately, my colleague was running some processing when I did that. I can't be exactly sure what his procedures were doing (I'm working on figuring that out), but his last issued commands before I stopped the database were:

```
(root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
(root) CMD (    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Upon restart we get some serious errors in the log (below). I've tried to start the database multiple times, to no avail. I've also rebooted the server; we still get these primary and secondary checkpoint errors, which I understand to be unfixable and requiring a database to be restored.

I wanted to check and see if anyone here has any workarounds that don't require a database restore. In other words, how can we get this database restarted without having to revert to a backup? Should a database restore be required, any recommendations for best practices with these specific errors in mind are welcome. Thanks!

```
2023-10-26 07:17:29.628 PDT [30714] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2023-10-26 07:17:29.629 PDT [13239] redacted@redacted FATAL:  canceling authentication due to timeout
2023-10-26 07:17:29.632 PDT [28456] redacted@redacted FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-10-26 07:17:29.640 PDT [29087] redacted@redacted FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-10-26 07:17:29.807 PDT [30714] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 30723) exited with exit code 1
2023-10-26 07:17:29.824 PDT [30716] LOG:  shutting down
2023-10-26 07:17:31.751 PDT [30714] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-10-26 07:17:35.675 PDT [13261] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-10-26 07:17:35.675 PDT [13261] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-10-26 07:17:37.826 PDT [13261] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-26 07:17:42.643 PDT [13262] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-09-18 16:02:09 PDT
2023-10-26 07:17:44.553 PDT [13262] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2023-10-26 07:17:44.553 PDT [13262] LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
2023-10-26 07:17:44.553 PDT [13262] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
pg_ctl: server did not start in time
```

Comment: Anything you can do to start that cluster will cause even more data corruption, and as you are running PostgreSQL v10, I am afraid you would continue working with the corrupted cluster. No, get your backup. That is the only safe way.

Comment: It looks like something catastrophic has happened, but it is hard to say what.  It looks like maybe the cluster that is trying to start up is not the same one as the one that was just shut down.  Did anything of note happen around 2023-09-18 16:02:09 PDT, like maybe a pg_upgrade?

Comment: @jjanes, that's a good question. We moved the database to a different volume around that time. However, the database has indeed been up and running since then. So, it's curious that the last known up time is September 18th.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to start some leftover remnant of the premove data directory.  Not sure how that would have happened, maybe after the move you manually started the database from the new location, but never updated the init.d for it to point to the new location. So when you restarted with init.d it picked the wrong place.

Comment: @jjanes that's a good thought. I do imagine that this is the first time the database was stopped since the move, so that would explain why we are only noticing this now given it's the first time trying to restart. I'll investigate the init.d file and see what I can discover. If you have any ideas what specifically to look for, that would be appreciated.